# XmlNode having no attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net

Guys I am using this code to get a XmlNode

```
public XmlNode CheckUserWithPassword(String username, String password) {
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load(xmlPath);
    XmlNode node = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(String.Format("Users/User[username='{0}' and password='{1}']", username, password));
    return node;
}
```

now the node I am getting that is here..

```
    XmlNode user = users.CheckUserWithPassword(Session["username"].ToString(),oldpassword.Text);
    if (user != null) {
        user.Attributes["password"].Value = newpassword.Text;
```

Now this is giving me a null at accessing the attributes, I have tried many methods. But whenever I try to access the attributes by key or by index it gives me null.
I have tried printing the outerXml of this node. And even that just shows the values without their tags.. 
rest of my functions are working fine, And it is returning the correct node, But it is coming without attributes !!! help me here 
Thanks.
Oh here is my XML with junk data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Users>
<User>
<name>Ibrahim</name>
<email>hdh@gmail.com</email>
<address>
</address>
<username>ok</username>
<password>ok</password>
</User>
<User>
<name>Aha</name>
<email>jhdhdd@gmail.com</email>
<address>EME DHA SECTOR</address>
<username>ok2</username>
<password>whatever</password>
</User>
<User>
<name>demo</name>
<email>demo@demo.com</email>
<address>sajdjahd</address>
<username>demo</username>
<password>demo</password>
</User>
<User>
<name>hello</name>
<email>hello@okd.com</email>
<address>
</address>
<username>pl</username>
<password>pl</password>
</User>
</Users>
```

Comment: Post a sample of your xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username` and `password` are *elements*, not *attributes*. Use `SelectSingleNode` again to get the `password` element.

```
if (user != null)
{
    var passwordElement = user.SelectSingleNode("password") as XmlElement;
    if (passwordElement != null)
        passwordElement.InnerText = newpassword.Text;
}
```

You could also shorten this whole algorithm by using a single `SelectSingleNode` with different XPath.

```
var xpath = String.Format("Users/User[username='{0}' and password='{1}']/password", username, password);
var passwordElement = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode(xpath) as XmlElement;
if (passwordElement != null)
    passwordElement.InnerText = newpassword.Text;
```

Comment: Well thankx it got working. But it is not updating the password in the XML file.

Comment: I have checked the passwordElement is not null, and that line does get executed but the data in xml doesn't update. Any help with that

Comment: Are you *saving* the XmlDocument? Making modifications on the XmlDocument in memory have no effect on the file.

Comment: `xmlDocument.Save("c:\your_filename_here.xml")` -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw229a22.aspx